# Photoswipe with Justified Gallery

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image-gallery, photoswipe

I successfully set up [Photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/) and also [Justified Gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) in my Rails project. Both of them work very nicely alone but I have trouble making them work together.

In my current (default) setup Photoswipe expects a tag hierarchy as follows:

```
<figure>
  <a href="...>
    <img src=".../>
  </a>
```

Justified Gallery is configured by default to recognize a container with any number of `<a>` tags with a nested `<img>` tag within like this:

```
<div id="mygallery" >
    <a href="...>
        <img src=".../>
    </a>
    <a href="...>
        <img src=".../>
    </a>
    <!-- other images... -->
</div>
```

So I would need to have Justified Gallery recognizing that `<figure>` tag. In their documentation it says you just have to add the following option:

```
selector: 'figure, div:not(.spinner)'
```

This part seems to work fine but it is also mentioned that it is necessary to extend the CSS rules and this is where I'm stuck. I would expect that prepending all or some `> a` selectors with a `> figure` selector should do the job but no. These are the rules that come with Justified Gallery:

```
.justified-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.justified-gallery > a,
.justified-gallery > div {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /* IE8 or Earlier */
}
.justified-gallery > a > img,
.justified-gallery > div > img,
.justified-gallery > a > a > img,
.justified-gallery > div > a > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
.justified-gallery > a > .caption,
.justified-gallery > div > .caption {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #000000;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.justified-gallery > a > .caption.caption-visible,
.justified-gallery > div > .caption.caption-visible {
  display: initial;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: "alpha(opacity=70)";
  /* IE8 or Earlier */
  -webkit-animation: justified-gallery-show-caption-animation 500ms 0 ease;
  -moz-animation: justified-gallery-show-caption-animation 500ms 0 ease;
  -ms-animation: justified-gallery-show-caption-animation 500ms 0 ease;
}
.justified-gallery > .entry-visible {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  /* IE8 or Earlier */
  -webkit-animation: justified-gallery-show-entry-animation 500ms 0 ease;
  -moz-animation: justified-gallery-show-entry-animation 500ms 0 ease;
  -ms-animation: justified-gallery-show-entry-animation 500ms 0 ease;
}
.justified-gallery > .jg-filtered {
  display: none;
}
.justified-gallery > .spinner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -24px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: initial;
  filter: initial;
  overflow: initial;
}
.justified-gallery > .spinner > span {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /* IE8 or Earlier */
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 0 4px 0 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
```

I have been playing around with this for quite a while but I can't make this work. Also I haven't been able to find a good example on the net.

Anyone has done this before or knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this exact problem by using:

```
selector: 'a, figure:not(.spinner)'
```

in the options and by replacing all the `div` selectors in the css with `figure`. So

```
.justified-gallery > div > img,
```

Would become:

```
.justified-gallery > figure > img,
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Justified Gallery v3.7.0 and PhotoSwipe v4.1.3 one only needs to replace the default selector by

```
'figure, > div:not(.spinner)'
```

Hence, for `<div id="mygallery">` one gets:

```
$('#mygallery').justifiedGallery({
    selector: 'figure, > div:not(.spinner)'
}).on('jg.complete', function () {
    initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('#mygallery');
});
```